# Expected first return time is finite for an irreducible Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

This is exercise 1.7 of Lawler's "Introduction to stochastic processes."

> Let $X_n$ be an irreducible Markov chain on the state space
> $\{1,\dots,N\}$. Show that there exist $C<\infty$ and $\rho < 1$ such
> that for any states $i,j$, $$ \mathbb{P}(X_m \ne j, m = 0,\dots,n \mid X_0 = i) \le C \rho^n. $$ Show that this implies $E[T]<\infty$, where
> $T$ is the first time that the Markov chain reaches the state $j$.
> (Hint: there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $i$, the
> probability of reaching $j$ after some time in the first $N$ steps,
> starting at $i$, is greater than $\delta$. Why?)

For the second part, I think the argument is
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[T] & =\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\left[t\times\mathbb{P}\{X_{m}\ne j,\forall m\in\{0,\dots,t-1\}\mid X_{0}=i\}\times\mathbb{P}\{X_{t}=j\mid X_{m}\ne j,\forall m\in\{0,\dots,t-1\}\}\right]\\
 & \le\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\left[t\times C\rho^{t-1}\times1\right]=(1-\rho)^{-2}<\infty.
\end{align*}

However, I don't understand how to show the inequality (and the Hint). Regarding the hint, the probability is
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_m = j, \exists m\in \{0,\dots, N\} \mid X_0 = i) = P_{ij}+P^2_{ij} + \cdots + P^N_{ij},
$$
where $P$ is the transition matrix. Thus, I can take $\frac{1}{2} \min_i \mathbb{P}(X_m = j, \exists m\in \{0,\dots, N\} \mid X_0 = i)$ as $\delta$, but I'm not sure this is the right way to find $\delta$. I see that
$$
 \mathbb{P}(X_m \ne j, m = 0,\dots,n \mid X_0 = i) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X_m = j, \exists m\in \{0,\dots, n\} \mid X_0 = i),
$$
so I'm guessing that $\delta$ should be of the form $\rho ^n$.

This question is asked on this forum multiple times ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193177/finite-irreducible-markov-chain-property), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961717/proofs-in-stochastic-processes), and [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531170/irreducible-finite-state-markov-chain)), but any of these were not helpful.

Comment: This reminds me of lemma 1.13. on page 10 of [Markov Chains & Mixing times](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf) by David & Yuval

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I understand the proof in the link, but I'm not sure how to show the bound given in Lawler for arbitrary $n$. If $n$ in the inequality $\mathbb{P}(X_m \ne j , m = 0,\dots, n\mid X_0 = i)\le C \rho^n$ is a multiple of $r$, where $r$ is taken as in the link, then it is immediate, but how about the cases where $n$ is not a multiple of $r$?

Comment: How do you prove (1.17) in lemma 1.13?. It seems induction is needed. (1.17) holds when k=1 but showing that (1.17) holds for k+1 if it holds for k is complicated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Irreducible finite-state Markov Chain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531170/irreducible-finite-state-markov-chain)